# Deallocating a char* returned from a function

Tags: c++, memory-management, char

When I create a function that returns a char* or const char*, is it assumed that the calling function must deallocate the returned value when it is finished with it?  Otherwise, how would it get deallocated? I'm looking some other code which calls a function that returns a char* and there is not a delete statement in the calling function.  Example:

```
char* foo();

void bar()
{
    char* result = foo();
    //I should have "delete result" here right?
}
```

EDIT:

So In my application here is foo:

```
LPTSTR GetTempPath(LPCTSTR fileName)
{   
    LPTSTR tempPath = new TCHAR[500];
    GetTempPath(500,tempPath);
    printf("Temp Path %ls\n",tempPath);
    PathAppend(tempPath, fileName);
    _tprintf(_T("New temp path: %s\n"), tempPath);
    return tempPath;
}
```

I wasn't sure how to write this without the new TCHAR.
I'm assuming this has to be deleted?  Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: It depends upon the definition of `foo`.  If it is required, that's not a library I would recommend using.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't make any assumptions. You have to read the documentation of the function. It could even return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, for all you know. This is one of the problems with such a function.

Comment: If the char* was not dynamically allocated using new, wouldn't it go out of scope when foo returned and hence be useless to bar?  And hence the delete should be necessary?

Comment: @EricKulcyk not necessarily. The pointer could point to something in a global object or a singleton. There is no way of knowing without knowing more about the function.

Comment: If the memory wasn't dynamically allocated in foo, you don't need to delete it in bar, because it will be destroyed after the bar func ends.

Comment: @EricKulcyk: in addition to what juanchopanza just said, it could well have been allocated with `malloc` so using `delete` instead of `free` would be an error.

Comment: In the case of a function returning a `const char*`, that means that it's pointing to something that should not be modified by the caller (and therefore you should not attempt to deallocate it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) two common conventions when a `char*` is returned by a function. You cannot tell which is in force without reading the documentation of the function.

1. The function returns a pointer to statically allocated memory. In which case the caller does not need to deallocate it.
2. The function returns a pointer to heap allocated memory. In which case the caller does need to deallocate it. The documentation for the function must specify how the caller must deallocate the function (free, delete etc.)

Now, since you are in charge of writing your own functions, you can choose whatever protocol you like. And in your case you should not return a `char*` from your functions. Choose a third way. Return a `std::string` and let the standard library take care of allocation and deallocation. Do it this way to make life easier for the consumer of the library.

In fact, since you are writing C++, you should be shunning `char*`. Sure you have to use C string when interacting with the Windows API. But leave it at that. Don't pass the pain on to the consumer of your library. Hide that complexity away.

In your situation I would make sure that you have a function that can combine two `std::string` instances. This could perhaps be implemented using `PathAppend`, but it's easy enough to roll your own. Then the only interaction you need with the Windows API is a function that returns the temporary directory in a string. That looks like this:

```
string GetTempDir()
{
    char buff[MAX_PATH+1];
    DWORD count = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH+1, buff); // I've omitted error checking
    return string(buff, count);
}
```

The code in this function is the only code that needs to deal with C strings. You can now forget all about them in the rest of your code which can treat this as a black box. Don't let the implementation details of the lowest common denominator C interface of Win32 leak into your nicely factored C++ code.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C++ and not C, you should use `std::string` to get rid of the problem.

Comment: You are assuming it represents a string. Maybe it is just a byte buffer.

Comment: `std::string` can represent a byte buffer just as easily.

Comment: @IronSavior except that it gives you an extra `0` at the end, if you access the underlying data array (since C++11 at least). But the idea is right: you return something that makes the intent clear, string vector or whatever.

Comment: @juanchopanza, if it's not a string then `vector<char>` works just as well.

Comment: @juanchopanza AFAIK, the null-terminator is only appended automatically for string literals.  I've never had problems using it as a buffer for binary data like so: `std::istringstream stream(std::string(a_vector.begin(), a_vector.end()));`  This copies the data, but the buffer will be automatically deallocated.  Just don't try and treat it like a C-string by accessing the underlying buffer directly--that's markedly un-C++ anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Yes, you get the null terminator, but it's just as easy to leave it out when you pass the size :)

Comment: @chris of course it is easy to leave out. But if you want to express that you are returning a byte buffer, why return a string? I was trying to make a pretty simple point that I thought was obvious. I am a bit surprised by all the comments.

Comment: @juanchopanza One reason might be because there's no non-deprecated `std::istream`-derived type that can be built from `std::vector`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Oh, I see what you were getting at now. I guess a string does imply it's meant to be used as a string, even if you can use it the same way as a vector for data operations.

Answer (score 2):

If `foo()` is in an external dynamic library, the library should provide some explicit way to delete result,if delete is required, or some other way to close the working session and so on.

Comment: This is the preferred way if it's a dynamic library, to prevent issues when the program and library don't link to the same runtime functions.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question you posed ("is it assumed that the calling function must deallocate the returned value when it is finished with it? Otherwise, how would it get deallocated?"):

No, the caller does not necessarily have to deallocate the string. Looking at [`man ctime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime):

```
char *ctime(const time_t *timep);
```

> The return value points to a statically allocated string which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

Which means you do not `delete` nor `free` the string it returns.